# Abstracting repeated Intermediate Stream-operations into a single Function

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream, method-reference, functional-interface

I am working with a large data structure where I want to perform a series of stream operations of the pattern:

```java
<some stream>
    .map(<method reference getter that returns List>).filter(Objects::nonNull).flatMap(Collections::stream)
    .map(<method reference getter that returns another sub-List>).filter(Objects::nonNull).flatMap(Collections::stream)
    .forEach(<perform some operations>)
```

I would like to compose a definition that abstracts the `map`, `filter`, and `flatMap` operations into a single function that I can apply to the stream with a `map` or pass the stream to; in my head it looks something like this:

```java
private static final <T,R> BiFunction<Stream<T>, Function<T,List<R>>, Stream<R>> mapAndFlatten =
    (inStream, lstGetter) -> {
        return inStream.map(lstGetter)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .flatmap(Collections::stream);
}
```

However, I'm not conceptualizing some things correctly. For one, the above syntax isn't right; is it obvious that I can't use generics with a `BiFunction`? Is there an existing framework/pattern to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Composing functions that make up subsequent `map` operations seems straight forward enough, so what about the addition of `filter` and `flatMap` is making it so hard for me to develop a solution? I'm struggling to find helpful information/examples. Am I conflating OO and functional concepts in a way that doesn't make sense?

Maybe I'm working too hard for a solution that doesn't need to exist; its not all that difficult to write `.filter(Objects::nonNull).flatmap(Collections::stream)`, but it feels verbose.

Comment: You cannot specify generic parameters for a variable or field declaration. However, you can make the entire field/lambda into a _method_ `<T,R> Stream<R> mapAndFlatten(Stream<T> inStream, Function<T, List<R>> lstGetter) { ... }`, but you would need to pass the Stream itself. Keep in mind, the lambdas within your stream operations operate on _single elements_, not the stream overall. Also, functional interfaces are isomorphic to (the "same" as) method signatures, and in fact are specified by method signatures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it obvious that I cant use generics with a BiFunction?

You can use generics with functions. But you can't provide a function which consumes a stream as an argument of the `map()` operation, which expects an argument of type `Function<? super T,? extends R>`. I.e. consumes a *stream element*, **not** a *stream*. And not that expected type is `Function`, not `BiFunction`.

And since you're flattening the data, it would not work with `map` because `map` is meant to perform *one-to-one* transformations (meanwhile you have *one-to-many* transformation).

As the hosting operation for `mapAndFlatten` you need either `flatMap()` or `mapMulti()`.

## flatMap()

[`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) expects a function consuming stream element and producing a stream of the resulting type `Function<T, Stream<R>>`.

That's how you can generate such function (Credits to *@Holger* for this concise implementation):

```
private static <T, R> Function<T, Stream<R>> mapAndFlatten(Function<T, List<R>> mapper) {
    
    return t -> Stream.ofNullable(mapper.apply(t))
        .flatMap(Collection::stream);
}
```

And the stream would look like this:

```java
Stream.of(t1, t2, t3)
    .flatMap(mapAndFlatten(Method_Ref_1))
    .flatMap(mapAndFlatten(Method_Ref_2))
    .forEach(Perform_Some_Operations);
```

*Dummy Example:* [*a link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/xME)

## mapMulty()

Another option would be to make use of Java 16 [`mapMulti()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)). This operation expects an argument of type `BiConsumer`, which in turn consumes an element of the initial type and consumer of the resulting type. Every element fed to the consumer of the resulting type becomes a replacement of the initial element.

```
public static <T, R> BiConsumer<T, Consumer<R>> mapAndFlatten(Function<T, List<R>> mapper) {
    
    return (t, consumer) -> {
        List<R> list = mapper.apply(t);
        if (list != null) list.forEach(consumer);
    };
}
```

And the stream might look as follows:

```
Stream.of(t1, t2, t3)
    .<R1>mapMulti(mapAndFlatten(Method_Ref_1)) // with mapMulti() type inference mechanism would potentially require a hand in the form of type-witness <R>
    .<R2>mapMulti(mapAndFlatten(Method_Ref_2))
    .forEach(Perform_Some_Operations);
```

*Dummy Example:* [*a link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/xMD)

**Note**

- When you need to return a Collection, it's always a good idea to return an *empty Collection* instead of `null`. You might find this suggestion in many authoritative sources, such as "Effective Java" by Joshua Bloch. It makes interaction with the resulting value way simpler.

Comment: Of course, the `flatMap` approach could be written as one step too, `return t -> { List<R> list = mapper.apply(t); return list != null) list.stream(): null; };`, not so different from the `mapMulti` variant. Alternatively, `return t -> Stream.ofNullable(mapper.apply(t)) .flatMap(Collection::stream);`

Comment: @Holger I really like this advice, incorporated the second approach into the answer. Should it be `return list != null ? list.stream() : Stream.empty();` in the first one?

Comment: The [contract of `flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function):~:text=If%20a%20mapped%20stream%20is%20null,instead) allows to return `null` instead of `Stream.empty()`. So you can also use `return list != null? list.stream(): null;` (could raise a stylistic debate whether to always use `Stream.empty()` though) I had a typo, a `)` where it should be a `?`…

Comment: @Holger You're right, *"If a mapped stream is null an empty stream is used, instead."*, that's an interesting peculiarity, which I didn't notice before.